# Deny access to the application for the role. Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have 2 applications: frontend and backend.

Users on frontend have role "client".

How do I disable access to the application backend users with "client" role. All other roles are allowed access. `site/login` on backend allow for all users.

I wrote the following code in my `main.php`file:

```
'as beforeRequest' => [
    'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
    'rules' => [
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'controllers' => ['site'],
            'actions' => ['login'],
            'roles' => ['?'],
        ],
        [
            'allow' => false,
            'roles' => ['client'],
        ],
    ],
    'denyCallback' => function () {
        return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['site/login']);
    },
],
```

I have error: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` in chrome.

Comment: Are users with the role `client` logged in to the frontend?

Comment: yes! For access to the frontend users must login.

Answer (score 1):

[From the guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accessrule.html#$roles-detail) `'roles' => ['?']`:

> matches a guest user (not authenticated yet)

Since the user is logged in they are stuck in a redirect loop caused by the second rule and the `denyCallback` i.e.

1. User is logged in but is of role `client` and is therefore not allowed.
2. Since user has been denied access, redirect to `site/login`.
3. See 1.

This can be fixed by omitting the `roles` element in your first rule:

> If [role] is not set or empty, it means this rule applies to all roles.

**HOWEVER THIS IS THE WRONG APPROACH**

Users who are logged in but are of role `client` should be denied access to the backend. Sending them to login will not help since they are already logged in. The proper course of action is to send them to the frontend's error page.

Comment: My first rule: `[
                'allow' => true,
                'controllers' => ['site'],
                'actions' => ['login'],
            ],`   But I still get error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`